# PHP adds to variable's end a space when used in foreach

Tags: php

Im working on a website with videos, but I have a problem. When I try to make a list of videos using foreach every variable of it includes a space on end even after trying to use str_replace... nothing worked. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$serialy_ = explode("\n", $serialy);
foreach($serialy_ as $serial) {
?>
<div class="serial_card" style="background-image: url(<?php echo "titles/" . $serial . ".png"; ?>);">
    <h3><?php echo $serial; ?></h3>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code as posted does not exhibit the symptom you describe.  Please [edit your post](https://superuser.com/posts/1470560/edit) to include the initial value of `$serialy`.  Just 4 or 5 lines should be sufficient. It seems likely that the extra spaces are in your data, and the problem is GIGO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your line delimiter is `\r\n` and not`\n` then `\r` is shown as a space in a HTML page.

Change the <strike>`$serialy_ = explode("\n", $serialy);`</strike> into:

```
$serialy_ = explode("\r\n", $serialy);
```